# Polite request regarding availability

Tags: sentence, formality, politeness

How do I ask if a person is available and to inform me, in a polite way?

Comment: Please let me know when you have a minute.

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky  Nice...

Comment: Well done @Hanky웃Panky to understand the original question. Why not post as answer?

Comment: Available for what? To speak to you for a minute? To fix your car? To *marry* you? Are you speaking to the person you want attention from later, or to a secretary, for example? Currently, it's *unclear what you're asking.*

Comment: Not really, he is asking for availability.  What he does once this happens is left unsaid, but also not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

*Please let me know when you have a minute*.

Comment: But we have no idea what exactly OP wants the person to do "when they are available"! It might be for a task that's expected to take a *week* or more!

Comment: This would generally imply *available to talk*, then the OP can tell that person the task even if it takes very long to finish it